# datetime.today attributes error

Tags: datetime, python-3.x

I'm trying to use the `Datetime.today` code to countdown seconds but every time that I call an attribute of the time, the interpreter denies that the attribute exists. For example:

```
x=datetime.today()
x= x.hour
print(x)
```

will return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\manuel\Downloads\graphics master v1.py", line 2, in <module>
x=x.hour
AttributeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute 'hour'
```

In other programs I have tested this to make sure that this is the correct attribute and syntax but in my master program I keep getting this error.

Comment: Your example code works fine, did you update it without updating the traceback?

Comment: @RonaldOussoren: It was originally written without parentheses.

Comment: That should have fixed the problem. Have you added a print statement before 'x=x.hour' to check if 'x' has the type you expect?

Answer (score 2):

datetime.today is a method not an attribute.

Try datetime.today()

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. If that was the issue, the error would be on the previous line.

Comment: @user2611919: [The parentheses `()` should help](http://ideone.com/EA6hfF). Check again.

Comment: @user2611919: The error wouldn't be on a previous line.  x would be equal to the method.  So you could do x=datetime.today and then do x().  Basically x would store the today method itself and not the returned class.